# React Controlled Input Validation

Tags: reactjs

I noticed a weird behavior where controlled components are not respecting the `minLength` and allowing a form to submit even though that condition is not met.

Validation works fine for uncontrolled components.

What is the reason for this behavior?

```js
export default function App() {
  const [uncontrolledSubmitCount, setUncontrolledSubmitCount] = useState(0);
  const [controlledSubmitCount, setControlledSubmitCount] = useState(0);

  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Uncontrolled (minLength: 10)</h2>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
          e.preventDefault();
          setUncontrolledSubmitCount(uncontrolledSubmitCount + 1);
        }}
      >
        <textarea
          type="text"
          minLength={10}
          maxLength={30}
          required
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <br />
        <span>Submit Count: {uncontrolledSubmitCount}</span>
      </form>

      <h2>Controlled (minLength: 10)</h2>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
          e.preventDefault();
          setControlledSubmitCount(controlledSubmitCount + 1);
        }}
      >
        <textarea
          type="text"
          minLength={10}
          maxLength={30}
          required
          value={content}
          onChange={(e) => setContent(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <span>Submit Count: {controlledSubmitCount}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a reproduction link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-violet-zwcct?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I can't reproduce this using your sandbox. There is no console log and no submit counter increase for the controlled component when the input length is under 10.

Comment: Seems to be a Chrome bug: Chrome 93.0.4577.51 - Error message if controlled component is empty, but minLength not honored otherwise /// Safari 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4) - works fine /// Firefox 91.0.2 - works fine

Comment: This is strange. As @digitalbreed said this is Chrome problem definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior happens only on Chrome as far as I tested it.

Based on [React official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) adding `value` to `textarea` it overrides HTML validations and it makes it "controlled" input and it ignores it overall. But only in Chrome.

The documentation also says there is an option to use `defaultValue`. I tried it at it works.

```js
<textarea
  minLength={10}
  maxLength={30}
  required
  defaultValue=""
  onChange={(e) => setContent(e.currentTarget.value)}
/>
```

[Working example from your codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-for-controlled-value-text-area-h1j9c)
With this solution you will solve Chrome problem but still keep `content` state with value that you enter inside `textarea`

**NOTE**:
If you try to use children value, React will throw an error that it is not supported for controlled `textarea`